# How to run componentwillmount lifecycle onclick?

Tags: reactjs

I am calling a function in `componentWillReceiveProps` to update the state in the function but the state is not getting changed.

Is there any way to update the state by calling `componentWillReceiveProps`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way componentWillReceiveProps is triggered is when the component's props change. Within this method you should compare current props to new ones and set your state accordingly. setState does not generally trigger this function and it will not be triggered on initial mount of the component.

Ref: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops